# Increment a hexadecimal string in C++

Tags: c++, string, c++11, hex

I want to increment a hexadecimal string in C++. The hexadecimal string starts "013802bf0000000000000000" and I want to increment it to "013802bf0000000000000001", ... ,"013802bf000000000000000f", ... etc till I hit " 013802bfffffffffffffffff ".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void main(double argc, char* argv[])
{
    string input = "013802bf0000000000000000";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      cout<< input << endl;


    }
    _getch();
}
```

I want to increment it to "013802bf0000000000000001", ... ,"013802bf000000000000000f", ... etc till I hit " 013802bfffffffffffffffff ".

Answer (score 3):

- If I counted correctly, you want to print all the variations of 16 hex digits, so you could use a `std::uint64_t`.
  I've commented out the line that would loop until the second to last number, and printed the first 16 instead. You'd have to print the last number separately. Otherwise you'd be looping indefinitely since all `std::uint64_t` are less than or equals `static_cast<std::uint64_t>(-1)`.
  **Notice** though, as @Yakk-AdamNevraumont points out in the comments, and I cite, that:

> To iterate through every 64 bit int and do even a trivial task on each
> one will take forever; if each trivial task takes a nanosection (10^-9
> seconds) it will take on the order of 1000 years to iterate over all
> 64 bit ints.

- The `fmt` library lets you print something with a given format:

  - `013802bf` is just a prefix text.
  - `{}` refers to the second argument passed to `fmt::print`, in this case, `i`.
  - `:016x` is the format specification for `i`: `x` for hexadecimal, `16` width, and `0` padding.
  - `\n` is a newline suffix.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/ahs6hx7xs)

```cpp
#include <cstdint>  // uint64_t
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <string>

int main() {
    //for (std::uint64_t i{0}; i < static_cast<std::uint64_t>(-1); ++i) {
    for (std::uint64_t i{0}; i < 16; ++i) {
        fmt::print("013802bf{:016x}\n", i);
    }
    fmt::print("...\n");
    fmt::print("013802bf{:016x}\n", static_cast<std::uint64_t>(-1));
}

// Outputs:
//
//   013802bf0000000000000000
//   013802bf0000000000000001
//   013802bf0000000000000002
//   013802bf0000000000000003
//   013802bf0000000000000004
//   013802bf0000000000000005
//   013802bf0000000000000006
//   013802bf0000000000000007
//   013802bf0000000000000008
//   013802bf0000000000000009
//   013802bf000000000000000a
//   013802bf000000000000000b
//   013802bf000000000000000c
//   013802bf000000000000000d
//   013802bf000000000000000e
//   013802bf000000000000000f
//   ...
//   013802bfffffffffffffffff
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in string as I want to checksum the increments into SHA256 hash.

Comment: Sure, you can use `fmt::format` to print something to a string (`str` in the next example): https://godbolt.org/z/1zMcs3bPa

Comment: The fact that all 64 bit ints are less than or equal to the max 64 bit int isn't the reason why the above program runs "forever".  To iterate through every 64 bit int and do even a trivial task on each one will take forever; if each trivial task takes a nanosection (10^-9 seconds) it will take on the order of 1000 years to iterate over all 64 bit ints.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Thanks for the point. It is much worth noticing. My message was that, if you use the commented `for` line instead of the other one, the program would continue running indefinitely after those 1000 years.

Comment: @rturrado I dunno, by then the C++ standard might have changed. ;)  (this is a joke)  But seriously, my point is that the OP's request will run forever in practice, and the OP doesn't look like they know it.  Mentioning that in the answer might help.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Done! I agree. I remember it crossed my mind when I wrote the answer, but I obviated it.